# TableView scrolls to bottom and perform some action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my application there is a table view.What I want to do is when I scrolls the table view and when it come to its end row I want to perform some action.
Please tell me which approach should I use to do this.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make a check  in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
```

when it loads the last row then call that method.

I think this will work. because table does not load all data at once but i loads data when user scroll

Comment: it works fine but the problem is when I reload table cellForRowAt method again gets called it again the method is calling.I want when the table is scroll it gets called only once.

Comment: what do u means it is calling the method before it scrolling down to last after calling reload method

Comment: it is getting called after reload data.

Comment: yes i check it but you can handle that problem by using a BOOL variable to be false before calling table reload method and then add this one in condition of method calling

Answer (score 1):

I think (don't the docs up here) but there is no method within the UIScrollViewDelegate that handles the scrolling to the bottom. There is when scrolling to top, but can't remember if there is scrolling to bottom. Check it please.

If not, the easy way is just to check the indexpath.row at cellForRow. If it is your last row, call whatever action you want.